# Is there any weekly pass for the Airport Express in Hong Kong?

Tags: tickets, public-transport, airports, hong-kong, hkg

I have to do 1 or 2 daily roundtrips between the Hong Kong International Airport (HKG) and Hong Kong Kowloon/Central station for one week. Using the normal fare, it is quite expensive: [~110 HKD (~=14 USD) one way](https://www.hongkongairport.com/en/transport/to-from-airport/airport-express.page) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20191030150819/https://www.hongkongairport.com/en/transport/to-from-airport/airport-express.page)). Is there any weekly pass for the Airport Express in Hong Kong?

Comment: IIRC the round-trip is the same price as the one-way fare when using Octopus. I don't think there are any passes, though.

Comment: @jcaron thanks, that's interesting. Is it the same price even if I exit the station before taking the return trip?

Comment: Yes, even if you stay all day long as far as I understand it. Note that on the Airport Express you don't even use your card at the Airport Station, only the other ones. There may be another option, but less convenient, and the savings are slim (though it depends on the actual number of roundtrips): a $435 City Saver pass to travel to Tsing Yi (using the Tung Chung line, NOT the Airport Express) (up to 20 round trips), then $65 per round trip from Tsing Yi to the Airport. Note however this is not currently possible, the Airport Express does not stop at Tsing Yi (or Kowloon) at the moment.

Comment: @Franck would a short detour via Tung Chung (via e.g. Bus S1) be an option to you? Definitely slower, but much cheaper. Season tickets (apart from a couple specific monthly tickets) aren't really a thing in Hong Kong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [MTR website](http://www.mtr.com.hk/en/customer/tickets/tf_index.html), you only pay 110HKD in total from Hong Kong Station if you return on the same day and use your Octopus card. This seems to be the cheapest option if you want to take the Airport Express.

Otherwise, as B.Liu suggests in the comments, take the Tung Chung Line from Hong Kong Station to Tung Chung (23.6HKD) and then get on a bus like S1, S56, S64, E33, etc. (~3.5HKD) to the airport. In this case, a [Tung Chung Line Monthly Pass](http://www.mtr.com.hk/en/customer/tickets/monthly_pass_extra.html) might make sense for you.